# unregisterReceiver kills my Toast popup

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, toast

I'm coding my very first Android app, a soundboard/ringtone app, and I'm having a problem with my Toast notification not showing up. I have a button that calls DownloadManager, downloads an mp3 from the internet, saves it to the sdcard, and assigns it as a ringtone. This all works fine, but I know I must unregisterReceiver after DownloadManager finishes. I want a Toast to pop up saying "Ringtone Has Been Set" once DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL comes thru, and it DOES work if I comment out my "onStop / unregisterReceiver" block. Once I reactivate that block, Toast does not display. I appreciate any help, and again, I am EXTREMELY new to android coding, or any programming at all. Thanks!

```
package com.gameringers.ffringers;

import java.io.File;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Query;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class DownloadActivity extends Activity {
private long enqueue;
private DownloadManager dm;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String songfile = intent.getStringExtra(FFVI.SONG_FILE);
    String songtitle = intent.getStringExtra(FFVI.SONG_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()

    {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {



                Query query = new Query();

                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = c
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                            .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ringtone Has Been Set!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

                          finish();

                    }

                  } 

                }   

           // }


    };  


    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));


    String path=(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/gameringers");
   // String filename="Test11"+".mp3"; 

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse(path+songfile)));

    File k = new File(path, songfile);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, (songtitle));
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "N/A");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    //Insert it into the database
    Uri newUri= this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
    this,
    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
    newUri);


    onStop();
    {

        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onStop();
    }

}







public void setringtone(View v) {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String songfile = intent.getStringExtra(FFVI.SONG_FILE);
    String songtitle = intent.getStringExtra(FFVI.SONG_TITLE);
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), songfile+songtitle,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);


    Request request = new Request(
            Uri.parse("http://www.gameringers.com/ringers/ff/"+songfile));

    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/gameringers",songfile);

    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);



}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onStop();
{

    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Above code from the question looks weird.
The right one should be

```
/** Receiver for download completion */
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String songfile = intent.getStringExtra(FFVI.SONG_FILE);
    String songtitle = intent.getStringExtra(FFVI.SONG_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);

    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()

    {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
                Query query = new Query();

                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = c
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                            .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ringtone Has Been Set!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

                          finish();

                    }

                  } 

                }   

           // }


    };  


    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));


    String path=(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/gameringers");
   // String filename="Test11"+".mp3"; 

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse(path+songfile)));

    File k = new File(path, songfile);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, (songtitle));
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "N/A");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    //Insert it into the database
    Uri newUri= this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
    this,
    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
    newUri);
}

@Override
public void onStop();
{
   unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
   mReceiver = null;
   super.onStop();
}


public void setringtone(View v) {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String songfile = intent.getStringExtra(FFVI.SONG_FILE);
    String songtitle = intent.getStringExtra(FFVI.SONG_TITLE);
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), songfile+songtitle,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

So with the code You have currently You just call onStop() and unregister receiver right in Yours onCreate() method. I believe it's just syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I've inserted that right after the onCreate method, just as you have shown, and Eclipse complains that "receiver" cannot be resolved to a variable. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: sandrstar, unfortunately this has not resolved my issue. Eclipse complains that "receiver" cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: ok. Provided more precise code snippet. It's just trivial. I would really suggest to start from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ not from Android for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onStop();
{
   unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
   mReceiver = null;
   super.onStop();
}
```

Is definitely correct. I just needed to figure out where to put it in my code. It works now!! Thank You!